# Row border end at specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I have question about VBA in Excel. 
I have border generated for each row, but I need to end border on specific column. 
I tryed to find solution for this, but nothing which will solve my problem.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(C_CI_LIST).Range(C_CI_COL_CATEGORY & endOfCIHeader + 1).EntireRow.Insert
            With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(C_CI_LIST).Range(C_CI_COL_CATEGORY & endOfCIHeader + 1).EntireRow
                            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
                        End With
```

This will generate me border for each row as I want, but I need have border for entire row and stop border at Column "AD", I tryed to change Range in many ways, but nothing helps. 
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: And in what ways did you try to change the `Range` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you apply the borader to the `.EntireRow` it of course formats the border of the entire row.

Instead you need to apply it to a specific range only. For example

```
Range("A1").EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
```

will format the border of the entire row 1, but

```
Range("A1", "Z1").Borders(xlEdgeTop)
```

will format the border of row 1 from column A to Z only. Alternativeley as @JvdV mentioned in the comment you can use

```
Range("A1").Resize(ColumnSize:=30).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
```

to format 30 columns of row 1 starting from column A.

Comment: Not worth an answer on its own because it would be inferior, but for OP: You could also try to `Resize`, like: `Range("A1").EntireRow.Columns(1).Resize(, 30).Borders(xlEdgeTop)`